# Как удалить всё содержимое всех скобок в тексте без использования функций и методов?

Tags: python

Задание:
Пользователь вводит текст. Нужно вывести этот текст, в котором скобки стоят на своих местах, но полностью пустыми. БЕЗ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ ФУНКЦИЙ И МЕТОДОВ!!!
Пример:

> У (лукоморья) дуб (зеленый) ---> У () дуб ()

Я пытался cделать тысячей способов: и списками, и в строкой, циклами, всем на свете. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Можете привести код последней попытки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение вас устроит?

```
import re

text = input("Введите текст: ")

result = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '()', text)
print(result)
```

Если нет, то :

```
#text = input("Введите текст: ")
text = "У (лукоморья) дуб (зеленый), очень (зеленый), но (возможно)(красный)"
result = ""
inside_bracket = False

for char in text:
    if char == '(':
        inside_bracket = True
        result += '('
    elif char == ')':
        inside_bracket = False
        result += ')'
    elif inside_bracket:
        result += ' '
    else:
        result += char

print(result)
```

Вывод: `У (         ) дуб (       ), очень (       ), но (        )(       )`

Comment: Есть мнение, что во втором elif должна не конкатенация пробела быть, а continue, так как в условии задачи между скобками на выходе ничего не должно быть.

Comment: Думаю это не существенно. Так как ТС просил помочь с идеей, я помог. Далее доработает как ему будет необходимо.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = 'У (лукоморья) дуб (зеленый)'
out, get = '', True

for c in text:
    if c == ')':
        get = True
    if get:
        out += c
    if c == '(':
        get = False
print(out)
```

```
У () дуб ()
```

Comment: Хотя в общем-то в другом ответе заготовка такого кода есть, только не оптимальная. Кстати, по какому принципу вы `text` отдельной строкой инициализировали, а две другие переменные - в одной строке? )

Comment: Разделил по смыслу. text - исходные данные, другие переменные - не исходные данные :) если оформлять этот код  как функцию, то text  был бы аргументом, а другие - локальными переменными